# When add four parameter of values, annotate sum not work

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm using Django 1.4 and Python 2.7.

I'm doing a Sum of some values... when I do this, this work perfect:

```
CategoryAnswers.objects.using('mam').filter(category=cat["category"], brand=cat["brand"], category__segment_category=cat["category__segment_category"]).values('category__name', 'brand__name','brand__pk').annotate(total=Sum('answer'))
```

And generate a query:

```
    SELECT `category`.`name`, `brand`.`name`, `category_answers`.`brand_id`, SUM(`category_answers`.`answer`) AS `total` 
FROM `category_answers` 
INNER JOIN `category` 
ON (`category_answers`.`category_id` = `category`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN `brand` 
ON (`category_answers`.`brand_id` = `brand`.`id`) 
WHERE (`category_answers`.`category_id` = 6  AND 
`category_answers`.`brand_id` = 1  AND 
`category`.`segment_category_id` = 1 ) 
GROUP BY `category`.`name`, `brand`.`name`, `category_answers`.`brand_id` 
ORDER BY NULL
```

But when I add a new value, this not work:

```
CategoryAnswers.objects.using('mam').order_by().filter(category=cat["category"], brand=cat["brand"], category__segment_category=cat["category__segment_category"]).values('category__name','category__pk','brand__name','brand__pk').annotate(total=Sum('answer'))
```

Seeing the query that is returned, the problem is django add on group by a wrong field (`category_answers`.`id`):

```
SELECT `category`.`name`, `category_answers`.`category_id`, `brand`.`name`, `category_answers`.`brand_id`, 
SUM(`category_answers`.`answer`) AS `total` 
FROM `category_answers` 
    INNER JOIN `category` 
      ON (`category_answers`.`category_id` = `category`.`id`) 
    INNER JOIN `brand` 
      ON (`category_answers`.`brand_id` = `brand`.`id`) 
WHERE (`category_answers`.`category_id` = 6  AND 
`category_answers`.`brand_id` = 1  AND 
`category`.`segment_category_id` = 1 ) 
    GROUP BY `category_answers`.`id`, `category`.`name`, `category_answers`.`category_id`, `brand`.`name`, `category_answers`.`brand_id` 
ORDER BY NULL
```

If I remove any parameter this work, so I do not believe this to be problem specific parameter... Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't resolve this, so... I do this with raw SQL query:

```
cursor = connections["mam"].cursor()        
cursor.execute("SELECT B.name, A.category_id, A.brand_id, SUM(A.answer) AS total, C.name FROM category_answers A INNER JOIN category B ON A.category_id = B.id INNER JOIN brand C ON A.brand_id = C.id WHERE A.brand_id = %s AND A.category_id = %s AND B.segment_category_id = %s", [cat["brand"],cat["category"],cat["category__segment_category"]])
c_answers = cursor.fetchone()
```

This is not the best way, but it's works. :)